# Detecting unintended weak link symbols

Tags: c++

In our company, just until recently, we were not using namespaces because some compilers could not support them well.

This lead to numerous occurrences of the following mistake:

**file_A.cpp**

```
class Node {
    Data *ptr;
    Node() { ptr = new Data; }
    ~Node() { delete ptr; }
};
```

**file_B.cpp**

```
class Node {
    vector<int> v;
    Point *pt;
    Node(int x,int y) { pt = new Point(x,y); v.push_back(0); }
    ~Node() { delete pt; }
};

void foo() {
    Node n(10,10);
    ...
}    // calls file_B::~Node() !!!
```

Each author `Node` did not know the existence of the other `Node`, but since he expected that this class name might be reused, he refrained from creating a .hpp file with it.

The compiler silently removes one of the destructors, as their signature matches, and the bug is hard to find, since it may not replicate in different computers.

Once the error had been identified, people gradually became aware of it, and they try to seal the definitions in unnamed namespaces, or avoid inilining the member functions in the class' body *[see below]*.

- **Question 1:** Since you can't trust that the programmer will always remember to program defensively, *is there a tool that can detect these "unintended weak link symbols" ?*

  By *unintended* I mean, `Node` classes were *not* defined in *.hpp* files, and at least one class member doesn't match between the class definitions...
- **Question 2:** If we don't use namespaces, but we *do* inline every function, is there a possibility that the auto-generated functions (copy-ctor, copy-assignment, destructor) will create the aforementioned "weak link bug" ?

---

Way 1: enclose in *unnamed* namespaces

```
namespace {
  class Node {
     Data *ptr;
     Node() { ptr = new Data; }
     ~Node() { delete ptr; }
  };
}
```

---

Way 2: avoid inlining

```
class Node {
   Data *ptr;
   Node();
   ~Node();
};

Node::Node()  { ptr = new Data; }
Node::~Node() { delete ptr; }
```

Comment: The sample code looks to me like it _ought_ to call `file_B::~Node()`

Comment: What compilers support namespaces badly? I'm just interested.

Comment: @MooingDuck: One of the 2 destructors whose signature match, will be kept. So, it might call the (file_B)::~Node()

Comment: @Roman: We've recently abandoned some 15-year-old SGI, HP windows and IBM compilers. I think a couple of them had issues with namespaces. I don't think C++ had been standardised by that time

Comment: Could you parse all the code and generate a list of class names? Then you could try to partition the codebase into autonomous systems and clean each of them.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, that could work, but it involves manual checks (correct me if I did not understand). If we had a, say, nighlty scan, we could get the bug as soon as it appears, rather than, say, once a month.

Comment: I probably didn't quite understand your goals. Do you want to *continue* developing without namespaces? In that case, can you enforce a strict discipline in which every team maintains a mandatory listing of classes?

Comment: @KerrekSB No, we *are* using namespaces. But we have no means of making sure *everybody* in the team will remember to follow the rules. There's bound to be a case every now and then that will forget, and another bug will go undetected.

Comment: "making sure everybody follows the rules"  -- Isn't that what code reviews are for?

Comment: @AShelly at what rate do you perform code reviews? For every file that is committed? Or randomly?

Comment: At this stage in our project (which had its first formal release a year ago), _every_ code change is reviewed.  (In practice, after an initial review, there may be some minor updates that are unreviewed, but nothing as major as a brand new class or method would get in without a formal review).

Comment: I believe the existing codebase actually violates the One Definition Rule, and thus the program is invalid C++. Your distinct types _must_ have -- after qualification -- different names. So it's not just "bad form": it's wrong. Trying to hack around it is not recommended.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, I am not sure I understand your argument, do you mean that both *Way 1* and *Way 2* stated above are wrong? What is the way to make them have *"after qualification" - different names*?

Comment: Rename the classes?  Or name one of the namespaces.

Comment: @Grim: Way one is correct (if a little error-prone). Way two is as incorrect as the original code. And giving them different names is easy -- use your keyboard.

Comment: @AShelly and @TomalakGeret'kal: Yes, I believe *Way 1* is the best. I assume that by *error prone* you mean that one might forget to set a class in an unnamed namespace. But if we assume that one may forget, then we can assume that simply renaming the classes (to, say `FILEX_Node` and `FILEY_Node`) then this is potentially error prone, too, in exactly the same manner. Even worse, the names now do not clearly read their intention.

Comment: If you can't trust your team to implement a correct solution to a well understood issue, you don't have a programming problem, you have a _programmers_ problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code base is large enough to justify the effort, you could **customize an existing compiler** to tackle with your issue:

1. The [LLVM](http://llvm.org/)/Clang compiler is customizable (it is in C++, and I don't know it very well).
2. The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (recent versions like **4.6**) is extensible, either thru *plugins* coded in C, or thru *extensions* coded in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). MELT is a (free, GPLv3 licensed) high level domain specific language to extend GCC.

In both cases, it is a effort of several days or weeks, and the most difficult is to understand partly the compiler internal representations (Gimple & Tree for GCC) and organizations (e.g. passes).

I am the main author of MELT and I will be delighted to help you with MELT, so feel free to contact me.

Comment: We're ~5 million lines, currently growing by about 1 million each year. But the side-effects of such bug are really costly.

Comment: I think it is an excellent use case for MELT... but again, you should be able to spend weeks on it, not only a few hours...

Answer (score 2):

["C++ and the linker"](http://blog.copton.net/articles/linker/index.html) is a very interesting read regarding this issue.  See specifically the section called ['Rules Without Enforcement Mean Nothing'](http://blog.copton.net/articles/linker/index.html#id28).

One insight is that you can detect "Weak" Symbols by parsing the object files, and looking for "W"s:

```
$ nm -C foo.o | grep doSomething
00000000 W doSomething()
```

So you may be able to add a post-process step which automatically collects these and lists the duplicates.   You can compare these to a master list of intended duplicates, and raise a flag if there are any new ones.

Another option might be gcc's [`-Fno-weak` option.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)  It's not clear from the docs what will happen on duplicates, but it might be interesting to find out.

The linked article also answers your second question (the "above phenomenon" refers to deleting all but one instance of a duplicated weak symbol):

> In some cases the compiler has to create a symbol
>   although it inlines the function. This can happen for example when a
>   function pointer references the function. So, the above phenomenon 
>   does not always disappear when optimization is enabled.